# having two googleinfo.plist file (1 for fire notification and 2 for google signIn )

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, plist, google-signin

I Have already done google sign In in my app. So I have an existing `googleserviceInfo.plist` file in my xcode. Now I have implemented firbase notification into my app and got another `googleinfo.plist` file. My older project is working fine but after adding new `googleifo.plist` of firebase notification and removeing older one (used for google signIn) getting crash into my app of URL schema.

I am not able to figure out which googleinfo. plist i should kept .

I am not able to figure out which `googleinfo. plist` I should kept.

Comment: Open both .plist file and check both, which have **DATABASE_URL**

Comment: connect your existing google project with firebase and than enable notification in project, that will give you new plist, with login and notification keys